# capybara & cucumber css locator not found

Tags: selenium, cucumber, capybara

I am new to cucumber and capybara and I am puzzled with the following error:

```
   When I click the "Search" button    # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:9
  Unable to find button #<Capybara::Element tag="button"> (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
  ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:11:in `/^I click the "([^"]*)" button$/'
  features/search.feature:9:in `When I click the "Search" button'
```

Within my feature I have:

```
When I click the "Search" button
```

My step looks like:

```
When /^I click the "([^"]*)" button$/ do |button_text|
  button_text = find('#gbqfb')
  click_button button_text
end
```

I have tried the 'click(button_text) and click_link methods. I am figuring its something probably obvious that I am not seeing. I am trying to find the css locator for a button element and then click on that element. I figure the regex doesn't need to be changed because I am changing what 'button_text' local variable is anyway. Or do I?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `first` and `find` method and then set click like this

```
first('.page a', :text => '2').click
find('.page a', :text => '2').click
```

for your cucumber

```
When /^I click the "([^"]*)" button$/ do |button_text|
  first('.page a', :text => "#{button_text}").click
end
```

**OR**

```
When /^I click the "([^"]*)" button$/ do |button_text|
  find('.page a', :text => "#{button_text}").click
end
```